# Post new form on every site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a post from a form. This is what I did and what worked so far:

**View**

```
<%= form_for @post, url: {action: "create"}, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :description %>
    <%= form.file_field :image %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= submit_tag"Post", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def new
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
end

def create
  @post = Post.create(post_params)
   if @post.save
     redirect_to @post
   else
     render :new
   end
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:description, :image, :user_id)
end
```

But now I would like to create a from, which will be placed in the `layouts/application.html.erb` and acceable from every route/site. But my problem is, that the variable `@post` is missing, because I parse it in the new function of the post itself. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create the form as below:-

```
<%= form_for Post.new, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :description %>
  <%= form.file_field :image %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= submit_tag"Post", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was a little bit faster. 10 seconds after I posted this question I found a solution on my own: `<%= form_for Post.new(params[:post]), url: { controller: "post", action: "create"}, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>`

Answer (score 0):

You just had to edit the first line of the view:

```
<%= form_for Post.new(params[:post]), url: { controller: "post", action: "create"}, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
```

As you can see I replaced the `@post` variable with a static call and added the controller attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can define your `@post` in `application_controller`, and then call it in `before_action`